# create menu page with collectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I'm struggle a lot. I want to make a menu page with collectionView like this.

[image: pageMenu]

I set my width collectionView like this

```
addSubview(menuCollectionView)        
menuCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
  menuCollectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
  menuCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
  menuCollectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -129),
  menuCollectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 33)
])
menuCollectionView.register(MenuCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellID)

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath)

        cell.backgroundColor = .red
        return cell
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: frame.width / 2, height: frame.height)
    }
```

but it end up like this
[image: pageMenu2]

the cell not fit with the width I setup, and it scroll to down. I was trying to replicate this tutorial from youtube [pageMenuVideo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rRhJGnSmEKQ&list=PL0dzCUj1L5JGKdVUtA5xds1zcyzsz7HLj&index=3) but it behave differently. please help me :(

Comment: in "sizeForItemAt" method why you give 'frame.width / 2', What is frame?

Comment: my collectionView inside UIView, cause I want to seperate the menu with the content. that use collectionView. it really identical with the video tutorial @KaushikOrangeApp

Comment: you have to calculate your menu item width and give it in "sizeForItemAt" method

Comment: i think this will help : https://github.com/rechsteiner/Parchment